# Can `foldMap f` be defined equivalently in terms of `fold/foldl` and `f`?

Tags: haskell, fold

In `Foldable t`, `foldMap` is defined based on `foldr`

```
foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
foldMap f = foldr (mappend . f) mempty
```

Can `foldMap f` be defined equivalently in terms of `fold` and `f`?
I guess `foldMap` is some kind of composition of `fold` and `f`, but `fold . f` doesn't make sense.

Can `foldMap f` be defined equivalently in terms of `foldl` and `f`?

Comment: Please do a little research by looking at the source for `Data.Foldable` first, and make an *attempt* to either define `foldMap` in terms of `foldl`, or provide what you think is proof (or at least evidence) that you cannot do so.

Comment: What `fold` are you referring to?

Comment: @chepner Given the context of the question, I think it's pretty clearly [this `fold`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold) that's being referred to. (I fully agree with your comment suggesting more effort on the part of the asker, though.)

Comment: I hope my answer helped, let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 4):

Almost, but not quite.

```
myFoldMap
  :: (Foldable t, Functor t, Monoid m)
  => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
myFoldMap f = fold . fmap f
```

This idea is where `foldMap` gets its name, but it has a `Functor` constraint that can't be satisfied by types like `Data.Set.Set`.

As for `foldr` and `foldl`, you can get the right types, and the right behavior for *finite* containers, but not the right behavior for *infinite* containers. Consider what `foldl` does for

```
data Stream a = a :< Stream a
  deriving Foldable
```

and what `foldr` does for

```
data RStream a = RStream a :> a
  deriving Foldable
```

In each case, you'll end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: `fold` is defined using `foldMap`:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#fold
Wouldn't this lead to an infinite loop?

Comment: @Niko, that's a *default* definition. It works often enough to be useful, but it doesn't work for every container.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is your way that  requires the foldable also be a functor the only possible way for representing `foldMap` by `fold` and `f`? Is it necessary that the foldable also be a functor? (2) How do you define `foldMap f` equivalently in terms of `foldl` and `f`?

Comment: @Tim, (1) think about what you need to give `fold`, compared to what `foldMap` is given. What do you need to do to adapt one to the other? (2) Try writing `foldMap f = foldl _ _` in an instance and see what the compiler tells you. Can you see how to plug the holes?

Comment: In both (1) and (2), I guess your approach is trying to bridge them at the type level, and I am also concerned about whether the definitions are equivalent. In (1) furthermore, my question is whether your way that imposes the extra functor requirement is the only way.

Comment: @Tim, fold + map gives an equivalent (but slower) implementation. As I explained already, `foldl` can only do so in some situations. For (2), you're really going to have to try it yourself and see what you find if you want to learn something.

Comment: Thanks.  I am unable to understand the part about foldr and foldl in your answer. First of all, I can't find out what `:>` and `:<` mean.

Comment: @Tim, they're data constructors I'm defining. I suspect it's time for to take a step back and work through some of the earlier chapters of a Haskell book.

Comment: What am I expected to step back to?   In `data Stream a = a :< Stream a`, the part after `=` is supposed to be a sequence of constructors separated by `|`, so I guess you new type has only one constructor `a :< Stream a`.  But I have never seen such a "convoluted" constructor in " the earlier chapters of a Haskell book". I am not sure what the constructor means, if it has some special keywords or predefined symbols, and what  `:>` and `:<` in the constructor mean

Comment: @Tim, they're just infix. An operator that starts with a colon is a constructor, like `:` for lists.

Comment: @Tim, just one. That could also be written `data Stream a = (:<) a (Stream a)`. It represents a list that is definitely infinite.

Answer (score 2):

If you carefully check the type of `foldr` and `foldl` you will see how easy could be:

look:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b

foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

so... what can we do here... mmm, do you know `flip`?

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

ok then:

```
foldMap' :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
foldMap' f = foldl (flip (mappend . f)) mempty
```